# Battlefield 3 PC black screen with sounds

Tags: pc, technical-issues, battlefield-3, origin

Since the last patch of Battlefield 3, I can't play it because the screen is black, but I can hear sounds in the background. I tried to repair the installation from Origin, but it doesn't resolve the problem. I think the issue is related to the fact that I have a Russian version of the game patched with the English language, but I don't know how to fix the problem.
I have a notebook: 1st generation Core i7, 4GB RAM, GeForce 420M (last driver). How can I fix this problem?

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling your graphics drivers? Or rolling them back even?

Comment: Last time I've got the same problem, it was because my Graphics card was not good enough to play the game. Did you run the game ok before or just barely?

Comment: The game was ok before, with medium-high details. There was only a bug when clicking CapsLock or Fn.

Comment: I forgot to say that the last driver 285.62(optimized for battlefield 3) gives me a problem of black screen with the OS at start-up too(I have to block/ibernate Windows7 to see something). So I prefer to wait for a driver's update, rather than downgrading it, maybe it can resolve both the problems. Anyway Battlefield 3 worked fine before the last patch.

Comment: black as totally black or with the "prompt" flashing in the right lower corner?

Comment: Totally black in multiplayer and with only the animated background (a soldier and a tank) in single player.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your language pack (tiny 2 MB):

- [How to Change Language Battlefield 3 Language Changer tool Origin - CJS CD Keys](http://www.cjs-cdkeys.com/battlefield-3-origin/bf3lang.html#patch)

Unfortunately, you will have to do this after every BF3 patch, so don't forget to bookmark this page (they are the main source). Hopefully, DICE won't update BF3 too often.

Answer (score -1):

Comment: Welcome to Gaming! Whilst this may answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to quote the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.